# Laravel trial mode middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make middleware for my app to do this logic for me:

1. Allow registered user access the panel for 60 days (based on `created_at` column of `users` table)
2. Then forbid user to access the panel unless admin gives the access to user (this access will be recognized by second table were `user_id` will be defined)

#### What do I need?

I don't need you to give me codes (*unless you want to show sample*) but the main thing that I'm asking here is your `ideas` and `solutions`.

**What do you think of this logic**? or **if you have any better idea**? etc.

**is using middleware the good way to achieve this or not**?

Answer (score 0):

For my little idea I think you can use midleware and it's the best way until someone offers something that I didn't know (I don't know much). midleware retrieves the user who issued the request and first checks whether he is eligible for the trial period based on his registration date. if not, he checks in the second table if the admin has given him access.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea but I think you could solve your problem with a column on the users table named something like 'access' which would be a boolean value. This value would be true when users register and allow the user to view the panel if the column is true.

Then after 60 days has passed from the created_at column change the 'access' column to false. You could check the created_at column in a scheduled command or job that runs each night and will change the column too false for users that have passed the 60 days limit.

Then in an admin UI or admin command you could just simply change the 'access' column back to true for certain users.